# Is there an AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool counterpart in OS X?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, calayer, avfoundation

I have come across the AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool class in iOS as I was in search of similar functionality in OS X. Does anyone know how I can accomplish the exact same thing (i.e. rendering a CALayer into a video) on OS X?